# I am facing problem that variable uri might not have initialised

Tags: uri

public static void repostWhatsApp(Context paramContext, boolean paramBoolean, String paramString) {

```
Uri uri;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
if (paramBoolean) {
    intent.setType("Video/*");
} else {
    intent.setType("image/*");
}
if (paramString.startsWith("content")) {
    uri = Uri.parse(paramString);
} else {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(paramContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    stringBuilder.append(".provider");
    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(paramContext, stringBuilder.toString(), new File((String)uri));
}
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", (Parcelable)uri);
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
paramContext.startActivity(intent);
```

}

Comment: What language is this? Consider adding tags.

Comment: It's a java language and share code